# How to access the bash PIPESTATUS array of an eval'd command?

Tags: bash

I have this code:

```
error(){
    time=$( date +"%T %F" )
    echo "Start : ${time} : ${1}" 1>&2

    result=$( eval "${1}" )
    if [ `echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}" | tr -s ' ' + | bc` -ne 0 ]; then 
        echo "command ${1} return ERROR" 1>&2
        exit
    else
        if [ "${2}" != "silent" ]; then
          echo "${result}"
        fi
    fi
}
```

I start testing command:

```
error "ifconfig | wc -l" "silent"
Start : 14:41:53 2014-02-19 : ifconfig | wc -l

error "ifconfiggg | wc -l" "silent"
Start : 14:43:13 2014-02-19 : ifconfiggg | wc -l
./install-streamserver.sh: line 42: ifconfiggg: command not found
```

But, I expect a different result. Example:

```
error "ifconfig" "silent"
Start : 14:44:52 2014-02-19 : ifconfig

Start : 14:45:40 2014-02-19 : ifconfiggg
./install-streamserver.sh: line 42: ifconfiggg: command not found
command ifconfiggg return ERROR  (<<<<<<<<<<<< This message)
```

I don't have it, because when bash runs a command with eval, as in

```
 eval "ifconfiggg | wc -l"
```

the $PIPESTATUS[@] array just contains "0" instead of the expected "1 0".

How can I fix this?

Comment: I make :    eval result="${1}; PIPE=\${PIPESTATUS[@]}"  And now i have: error "false| false | true | false | false " "silent" Result:      Start : 07:46:14 2014-02-20 : false| false | true | false | false 
0 1 0 1 1 -- pipe   Not work only first, wtf?

Answer (score 3):

The `eval` starts a new shell context which has a separate `PIPESTATUS[]` array. The lifetime of this context ends when the `eval` ends. You can communicate this array to the parent context through assigning to a variable, say, `PIPE` as follows:

```
$ eval 'ifconfiggg | wc -l; PIPE=${PIPESTATUS[@]}'
bash: ifconfiggg: command not found
0
$ echo $PIPE
127 0
```

Note the single quotes to prevent `${PIPESTATUS[@]}` from expanding too early.

Wrapping this in yet another `result=$(...)` does not work, since this creates yet another shell context. I suggest instead something along the lines of

```
eval "${1}; "'PIPE=${PIPESTATUS[@]}' >result.out 2>result.err
# do something with $PIPE here
# do something with result.out or result.err here
```

Note the use of both double quotes followed by single quotes.

Comment: This don't work for code:result=$( eval "${1}; PIPE=${PIPESTATUS[@]}" )
  echo "${PIPE}"
don't work! =( return empty

Comment: Of course it doesn't, since it doesn't pay attention to what I wrote in the note. This needs proper quotes. To work in yet another $() needs even more quotes.

Comment: I change on single quotes (don't edit message, sry). You can write working code? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's right to say "`eval` starts a new shell context". As you demonstrate, variables set within the `eval` context are preserved in the surrounding context. Bash simply treats `eval` as a single command, even if it's evaluating a multi-command pipeline, and therefore doesn't preserve its `PIPESTATUS`. This makes more sense in the context of a multi-command pipeline, e.g. `false | eval 'true | false'` results in `PIPESTATUS=(1 1)`, not `PIPESTATUS=(1 0 1)` which (I suspect) would be more surprising.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Jens for posting this information. I noticed for

```
eval "${1}; "'PIPE=${PIPESTATUS[@]}' >result.out 2>result.err
```

that it's better to use parentheses around array PIPESTATUS. Otherwise it seems to be interpreted as string and the complete result is in ${PIPESTATUS[0]} only. So

```
eval "${1}; "'PIPE=(${PIPESTATUS[@]})' >result.out 2>result.err
```

is working as expected.

Comment: **typo!** ... and the complete result is in `${PIPE[0]}` only ... not in `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` only